# How to inject Django template code into template through {{ variable/method }}?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-templates

I have a model Reservation which I use in many templates. It's handy to create it's own `HTML/Django` snippet which is being injected into the template through variable/model method.

The raw `HTML` is correct using the method but Django template language isn't interpreted correctly.

This is a Reservation method:

```
def get_html_description(self):
    return """<ul>
                <li><b>ID:</b> {{ reservation.id }}</li>
                <hr>
                <li><b>From:</b> {{ reservation.get_text_destination_from }}</li>
                <li><b>To:</b> {{ reservation.get_text_destination_to }}</li>
                <hr>
                <li><b>Date:</b> {{ reservation.get_date }}</li>
                <li><b>Time:</b> {{ reservation.get_time }}</li>
              </ul>"""
```

Now I'm trying to inject this code into the template:

```
<div class="events">
     {% for reservation in data.1 %}
         <div class="event">
              <h4>{{ reservation.get_text_destination_from }} to {{ reservation.get_text_destination_to }}</h4>
              <div class="desc">
                  {% autoescape off %}{{ reservation.get_html_description }}{% endautoescape %}
              </div>...
                    ...
```

Unfortunately it renders something like this:

[image]

Do you know what to do? I've already tried filter `|safe` and `{% autoescape off %}`

Comment: It might be a better idea to create an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) rather than storing templates in your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is double substitution and I don't think the Django templating engine will do that. Since you are pulling the data from a `Reservation` instance, I would just fill it in using string substitution. For example:

```
 return """<ul>
                <li><b>ID:</b> {pk}</li>
                <hr>
                <li><b>From:</b> {destination_from}</li>
                ...
           </ul>""".format(pk=self.id,
                           destination_from=self.reservation.get_text_destination_from)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't ask the template to do it, if you really want to continue to use this method then just do string formatting, and mark it as safe.

```
desc = """<ul>
            <li><b>ID:</b> %(id)s</li>
          </ul>""" % { 'id': self.id }

return mark_safe(desc)
```

Etc.